# QGIS Refactor fields error

Tags: qgis, error, qgis-processing, fields-attributes

I am using the Refactor fields in the Processing Toolbox to change order of attribute columns. 3 of the fields have red text in the Expression column and when I Run the changes I get an error:

```
Algorithm Refactor fields starting...

Parser error in expression "Site name": syntax error, unexpected COLUMN_REF, expecting $end
```

How do I fix this??

Comment: What QGIS version and platform (Windows, Linux etc) are you using? Could you use the **Table Manager** plugin instead to move the attribute columns?

Comment: Are you working with a shapefile or some other dataset?  I haven't been able to get Refactor fields to work (doing other things) so if you don't get an answer and you are using or can use a shapefile, a workaround is to make a copy/backup, open the dbf in Libre Office, change the field order there, save and reopen the shapefile.  While in Libre Office, do NOT sort and do NOT edit the shape or the ID fields.  Click through the warnings about some features may not be saved to dbf.  Check your data to make sure all is well when you are done.  Excel can't do this; it can't save a dbf as a dbf.